# Внезапно перестал работать интернет на виртуальной машине с Linuxmint и Ubuntu, как настроить?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Внезапно перестал работать интернет на виртуальной машине с Linuxmint и Ubuntu, как настроить? На самой системе Windows 10 все работает. Пробовал сделать другие виртуальные машины с Linux OS, все равно интернет не работает.

Средство виртуализации Oracle VM Virtual box

Comment: вы бы хоть средство виртуализации указали

Comment: Oracle VM Virtual box, спасибо

Comment: Как сеть организована? Сетевым мостом?

Comment: Home CosmosTV cable